How to have hashed shaded lines in TiKZ?
The following MWE,
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[pattern color=black, pattern=north west lines] (8,-.75) rectangle (10,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

produces:

How can I make it shaded? On left of the figure I want it to be black and on the right, I want it to be black!50!.
I have found commands like \shadedraw or attributes like [left color=black] and right color=black!50 but could not succeed to make them work.

You could add a path fading to your picture:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,fadings}

\tikzfading[
name=fade right,
left color=black!0, 
right color=black!80]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[pattern color=black, pattern=north west lines,path fading=fade right] (8,-.75) rectangle (10,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



I did not know the English vocabulary word "fading". Thanks!

@JKHA You're welcome!
